# Problems applying Subsurface Division with Armature

Tags: armature, weight-painting, subdivision-surface, unity

Noob here!
I modeled a penguin for a Unity game and made an armature and already made walk cycles and idle in the actions.
The problem is that in order to use the model on Unity, I have to export the model in FBX, that means applying the surface subdivision and my Mesh is completely deformed at the arms and body.
In my file blender, I don't have weight paint on my penguin, but I tried, it doesn't solve the problem completely.
I also removed the parenting, applied the surface subdivision, removed the vertex bones parenting in the list and reapplied the parenting and I don't know why the armature doesn't want to reparent with the penguin.
I also Merge the Verticles and it seems like there is no double Verticles.

Here is the Blend file:
https://we.tl/t-MMobInlnqG

Hope someone can help me!
Have a good day :) And Thank you!!

[image]

Before Applying Sudivision S

[image]

After Applying Subdivision S

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's a question of weight painting. If you keep the *Subdivision Surface* modifier you can already see that some bones should not control some vertices, like for example the shoulder bones have influence on the arms or armpits. So maybe correct this as much as possible, apply the *Subidivision Surface* modifier (do you need a level of subidivision of 3? Also do you need the *Auto Normalize* option?) and correct again on the high-poly if it's still not good:

[image]

Also a function that helps when you'll work on the high-poly is the *Weights > Smooth*, and select the *Subset > All Groups* in the *Operator* box:

[image]